# NGINX - How to check whether the requested domain and server_name (HOST header value) are same

Tags: nginx, server-name, hostheaders

I have multiple services running in a machine behind NGINX,

Using server_name configured for few application's end points

```
server {
    server_name my_app_1;
    listen *:443;
    ....
}
server {
    server_name my_app_2;
    listen *:443;
    ....
}
```

Since i want one service to be a default application for my machine, I exposed it as a default-server

```
#mydomain.com
   server {
        listen *:443 default_server;
        location / {
           ...
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when the NGINX receives a request for https :// mydomain.com with HOST header set as 'another.app.com', the default_server starts serving..
It returns 404,

But I want to restrict the default-server or another server to serve only when HOST header and request domain are same.

something like,

```
server {
    server_name $request_domain;
    listen *:443;
}
```

Please help me on this.

Note: We can give the possible combination of all domain names for server_name. In my case IPs are not static / dynamic

Answer (score 4):

You can use below redirect rule in the virtual host.

```
server_name test1.com;
set $domain_name test1.com;
if ($http_host != $domain_name) {
return 403;
}
```

The above rule will allow when http_host and domain name match. Otherwise it will give 403 error.